# How to loop over a list of dict elements deep 3 in Ansible

Tags: ansible, nexus

I have the following variables in my var file:

```yaml
repo_type:
  hosted:
    data:
      - name: hosted_repo1
        online: true
        storage:
          blobstarage: default
          write_policy: allow_once
      - name: hosted_repo2
        online: true
        storage:
          blobstarage: default
          write_policy: allow_once
  proxy:
    data:
      - name: proxy_repo1
        online: true
        storage:
          blobstarage: default
          write_policy: allow_once
      - name: proxy_repo2
        online: true
        storage:
          blobstarage: default
          write_policy: allow_once
  group:
    data:
      - name: group_repo1
        online: true
        storage:
          blobstarage: default
          write_policy: allow_once
      - name: group_repo2
        online: true
        storage:
          blobstarage: default
          write_policy: allow_once
```

I want to configure a task to to loop over (hosted,proxy and group) and body over data dict.

Here is the task:

```yaml
- name: Create pypi hosted Repos
  uri:
    url: "{{ nexus_api_scheme }}://{{ nexus_api_hostname }}:{{ nexus_api_port }}\
      {{ nexus_api_context_path }}{{ nexus_rest_api_endpoint }}/repositories/pypi/{{ item.key}}"
    user: "{{ nexus_api_user }}"
    password: "{{ nexus_default_admin_password }}"
    headers:
      accept: "application/json"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body_format: json
    method: POST
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: "{{ nexus_api_validate_certs }}"
    body: "{{  item  }}"
    status_code: 201
  no_log: no
  with_dict: "{{ repo_type}}"
```

I have tried `with_items`, `with_dict` and `with_nested` but nothing helped.

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'data'

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported by @larsk, you actually didn't manage to explain clearly how you are trying to loop over your data and what your api call is actually expecting.

But you are in luck this time since I have messed around with Nexus quite a bit (and I think [I actually recognize those variable names and overall task layout](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/0c6c4a4f4331a4b19287d4f488552778825bfd41/tasks/call_script.yml#L3))

The Nexus Repository `POST /v1/repositories/pypi/[hosted|proxy|group]` API endpoints are expecting one call for each of your repos in `data`. To implement your requirement you need to loop over the keys in `repo_type` to select the appropriate endpoint and then loop again over each element in `data` to send the repo definition to create.

This is actually possible combining a `dict2items` and `subelements` filters in your loop as in the below playbook (not directly tested).

The basics of the transformation are as follow:

1. transform your dict to a key/value list using `dict2items` e.g. (shortened example)

   ```yaml
   - key: hosted
     value:
       data:
         - <repo definition 1>
         - <repo definition 2>
   [...]
   ```
2. use the `subelements` filter to combine each top element with each element in `value.data` e.g.:

   ```yaml
   - # <- This is the entry for first repo i.e. `item` in your loop
     - key: hosted # <- this is the start of the corresponding top element i.e. `item.0` in your loop
       value:
         data:
           - <repo definition 1>
           - <repo definition 2>
     - <repo definition 1> # <- this is the sub-element i.e. `item.1` in your loop 
   - # <- this is the entry for second repo
     - key: hosted
       value:
         data:
           - <repo definition 1>
           - <repo definition 2>
     - <repo definition 2>
   [...]
   ```

Following one of your comments and from my experience, I added to my example an explicit json serialization of the repo definition using the `to_json` filter.

Putting it all together this gives:

```yaml
- name: Create pypi hosted Repos
  uri:
    url: "{{ nexus_api_scheme }}://{{ nexus_api_hostname }}:{{ nexus_api_port }}\
      {{ nexus_api_context_path }}{{ nexus_rest_api_endpoint }}/repositories/pypi/{{ item.0.key }}"
    user: "{{ nexus_api_user }}"
    password: "{{ nexus_default_admin_password }}"
    headers:
      accept: "application/json"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body_format: json
    method: POST
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: "{{ nexus_api_validate_certs }}"
    body: "{{ item.1 | to_json }}"
    status_code: 201
  no_log: no
  loop: "{{ repo_type | dict2items | subelements('value.data') }}"
```

Comment: Apologies for not clear enough.  @ Zeitounator - Thanks for the reply. I've just tried and giving me this error ```MSG:

could not find 'data' key in iterated item {'key': 'hosted', 'value': {'data': [{'name': 'hosted_repo1', 'online': True, 'storage': {'blobstarage': 'default', 'write_policy': 'allow_once'}}, {'name': 'hosted_repo2', 'online': True, 'storage': {'blobstarage': 'default', 'write_policy': 'allow_once'}}]}}```

Comment: My first post had a typo that has been corrected since in the last line of the example. The parameter to `subelements` should be **value.data**

Comment: Thanks. Now getting  - Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\"\n} .   ```(item=[{'key': 'hosted', 'value': {'data': [{'name': 'hosted_repo1', 'online': True, 'storage': {'blobstarage': 'default', 'write_policy': 'allow_once'}}, {'name': 'hosted_repo2', 'online': True, 'storage': {'blobstarage': 'default', 'write_policy': 'allow_once'}}]}}, {'name': 'hosted_repo1', 'online': True, 'storage': {'blobstarage': 'default', 'write_policy': 'allow_once'}}]) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",``` sorry not possible add all the error message.

Comment: Now this is a problem returned by the nexus API so at least your initial problem is solved: you are now looping with your example data. I have an idea of what might be happening so I made a last edit, adding the `to_json` filter. If this does not work, you will have to debug this further on your side. And note: comments are note meant for large portion of code nor to add info necessary to answer your question. You should edit your question for that.

Comment: I also suggest you review in detail the api endpoint documentation accessing `https://<your_nexus_uri>/swagger-ui` and check in depth all the possible parameters and their specific type to send in request body because I already spotted several typos (like `blobstarage` which should be `blobStoreName`.....). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!. to_json didn't help. i will debug further at my end.

Comment: You were right, It was an example data but for testing i'm using correct parameters as per https://<your_nexus_uri>/swagger-ui documentation. .

Comment: Thanks again for the solution, i made a mistake with the code at the time and it worked after correcting the mistake  without any debug/modifications from my end.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to loop over the contents of the `data` keys as a flat list, you could do it like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "repo {{ item.name }} write_policy {{ item.storage.write_policy }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ repo_type | json_query('*.data[]') }}"
```

That uses a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) expression to get the `data` key from each
top-level dictionary, and then flatten the resulting nested list.  In
other words, it transforms you original structure into:

```
- name: hosted_repo1
  online: true
  storage:
    blobstarage: default
    write_policy: allow_once
- name: hosted_repo2
  online: true
  storage:
    blobstarage: default
    write_policy: allow_once
- name: proxy_repo1
  online: true
  storage:
    blobstarage: default
    write_policy: allow_once
- name: proxy_repo2
  online: true
  storage:
    blobstarage: default
    write_policy: allow_once
- name: group_repo1
  online: true
  storage:
    blobstarage: default
    write_policy: allow_once
- name: group_repo2
  online: true
  storage:
    blobstarage: default
    write_policy: allow_once
```

When run using your example data, this produces as output:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=hosted_repo1) => {
    "msg": "repo hosted_repo1 write_policy allow_once"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=hosted_repo2) => {
    "msg": "repo hosted_repo2 write_policy allow_once"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy_repo1) => {
    "msg": "repo proxy_repo1 write_policy allow_once"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy_repo2) => {
    "msg": "repo proxy_repo2 write_policy allow_once"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=group_repo1) => {
    "msg": "repo group_repo1 write_policy allow_once"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=group_repo2) => {
    "msg": "repo group_repo2 write_policy allow_once"
}
```

If you're trying to do something else, please update your question so
that it clearly shows the values you expect for each iteration of your
loop.

Comment: @ larsks: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I want to loop through each key in data for as body: "{{  item  }}". Would that be possible? Also how to pass (hosted,proxy and group) as variable to.    ```url: "{{ nexus_api_scheme }}://{{ nexus_api_hostname }}:{{ nexus_api_port }}\

      {{ nexus_api_context_path }}{{ nexus_rest_api_endpoint }}/repositories/pypi/{{ item.key}}"```